# convert memcpy() code from x86 to x64 platform

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, 64-bit, memcpy

this code is memcpy() on x86 platforms . but I need to memcpy() on x64 platform .

```
_asm { 
        mov esi, src 
        mov edi, dest 
        mov ecx, nbytes 
        shr ecx, 6 // 64 bytes per iteration 

loop1: 
    movq mm1,  0[ESI] // Read in source data 
    movq mm2,  8[ESI] 
    movq mm3, 16[ESI] 
    movq mm4, 24[ESI] 
    movq mm5, 32[ESI] 
    movq mm6, 40[ESI] 
    movq mm7, 48[ESI] 
    movq mm0, 56[ESI] 

    movq  0[EDI], mm1 // Write to destination 
    movq  8[EDI], mm2 
    movq 16[EDI], mm3 
    movq 24[EDI], mm4 
    movq 32[EDI], mm5 
    movq 40[EDI], mm6 
    movq 48[EDI], mm7 
    movq 56[EDI], mm0 

    add esi, 64 
    add edi, 64 
    dec ecx 
    jnz loop1 

    emms 
}
```

I have no knowledge of x64 assembly language .
how convert this code from x86 to x64 ?

Comment: Do you have reasons to suspect that you'd do any better than the implementation in `libc`? Feel free to look at [what others have done](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/arch-x86_64/string/sse2-memcpy-slm.S).

Comment: I have strong reasons to suspect that it is a lot slower than a good implementation, because it uses MMX registers.

Comment: I strongly suspect that if you understand x86 assembly you can very easily translate this to X64 by doing perhaps one google search.

Comment: The link Laybrary that speed is better than the c ++ : http://agner.org/optimize/#asmlib

Answer (score 1):

I suppose replacing esi and edi with rsi and rdi should do the trick. Although it will not become faster (or fast).
Other than pointers, x64 is backwards compatible with x86.

In general better make a C loop or use the default memcpy. It will generate much better code.

Comment: C loop is likely to be slower, but otherwise I agree.

Comment: The link Laybrary that speed is better than the c ++ : http://agner.org/optimize/#asmlib